# Any possibility to track home button press event in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, appframework

Hello IS there any event to track Home button press in Android and IOS using phonegap phonegap build.

I search on home button press event but i found only back button events.

Answer (score 2):

What about pause event?
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

You can perhaps track also back button events and exclude them if you really want to count home button clicks..

Answer (score 0):

You can track it using Google Analytic Cordova Plugin.

https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

example

You just call it one time only everytime the app launch.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')
}
```

Track screen you need to insert each page that you want to track.

Page 1

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 1')
```

Page 2

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 2')
```

Page 3

```
window.analytics.trackView('Page 3')
```

User Id is your user that use your app. You can grab it from your database.

```
window.analytics.setUserId('1')
```